# print a int value to char sequence

Tags: python

I have a 4 byte int variable which contains 'h264' chars. what's proper way to print it as char sequence as well.

```
x = 0x68323634 # h264
print(str(x))
```

current output is:

```
1748121140
```

expect output is:

```
h264
```

Comment: Doable with `int.to_bytes` or `struct.pack`, but how did you get that integer value? Checking earlier might make things less circuitous.

Comment: Show us how `'h264'` was converted to that integer value.

Comment: It's received from a encoder.

Comment: Received how, though, in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
>>> x = 0x68323634
>>> x.to_bytes(4, "big").decode("ascii")
'h264'
```

Comment: Not sure why I got error: TypeError: to_bytes() missing required argument 'byteorder' (pos 2)

Comment: @lucky1928 I'm using Python 3.12.2 on Win10 which may be different from your environment. If a second argument is required, use `.to_bytes(4, 'big')`.

Comment: @lucky1928 As I just checked, the default value for `byteorder` does not exist until Python 3.11. So if you are using a version below that, you need to manually specify a `byteorder` value which should be `'big'` in your case.

Comment: Good catch, my python is 3.10.12. will upgrade it. many thanks.